# Android passing a method return to a function

Tags: android, return-value, android-alertdialog

```
public class DialogWithInputBox extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString().trim(); // important line!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return value;
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert.show();    
}
```

Above code gives a dialog with ok and cancel button. There is a local variable `value`. I want to pass this to another method. when I put a return + local variable, it is asking me to change onclickevent listener type.

Comment: hi, i think you want to do like , when i press ok button then you want pass value of edit text to next activity right?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, you can't return a value from a method whose return type is `void`. You have two choices:

1. If you need this value to stay around for a while, you can make `value` a field of your Activity, and just set it in your click handler. Then you can refer to it from other methods in the Activity.
2. If you only need to use it temporarily, then pass `value` as an argument to the other method you need to call, *directly from your click handler*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure java issue. You could pass a value to class members

```
public class DialogWithInputBox extends Activity {

private String dest;

..
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      dest = input.getText().toString().trim();
..
```

Comment: :I mentioned onClick as String but it is asking me to give void,parameters are int and string.what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the return type of a method.

It is totally unclear what you expect by returning an value.
Return to whom?? What should be done with that string?

The caller would get the value but the caller (the positive button) does not expect anything
The code you have given to us, just tells the positive button to call method onClick.
And the button will do that but nothing more. The button does not know anything at all how your onClick method is implemented.

The only way is to set a member var or to call a method with that value.